# take variable from middle of url and append it to the very end

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I have links like this

- `http://panel.domain.com/users/index.php?user=8`
- `http://panel.domain.com/users/settings/index.php?user=8`

I want to rewrite them into this:

- `http://panel.domain.com/users/8/`
- `http://panel.domain.com/users/8/settings`

I want it to take anything after the user id and put it after users, and then go to index.php of that page and put the userid at the end, like this: `users/USERID/chain/of/directories/index.php?user=USERID`

I can make the first rewrite with this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?user=$1
```

I've tried doing something like this

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^users/(.*)/$ $2/index.php?user=$1
```

$2 is first, because it should be everything AFTER `users/ID/`, and then $1 should be `/ID/`, which gets placed at the end of the directory chain: `users/ID/settings/index.php?user=ID`

But I really just can't figure out how it works. I don't know what it is that makes `$1` and `$2` work, and I don't understand regex. I've been looking through the Pearl docs all night and just trying to slap stuff together but I just don't get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this .htaccess code in  site root `.htaccess`:

```sh
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^users/([\w-]+)(/.+)?/?$ /users$2/index.php?user=$1 [L,QSA]
```

**This assumes you don't have any .htaccess inside `/users/` directory.**

Comment: modifying it to this `RewriteRule ^users/([\w-]+)(/.+)?/?$ /users/$2/index.php?user=$1 [L,QSA]` (a slash between users and $2) and it works perfectly, thank you!

Comment: Actually we are already capturing `/` in `$2` which is why I omitted it from my answer

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following, written and tested based on your shown samples. You could catch both the variables in a single shot itself, you need not to use 2 conditions for this one.

Place this .htaccess file inside your users folder only.

Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteBase /users/

RewriteRule ^/?$ index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(\d+)/?$ index.php?users=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^(\d+)/.*$ settings/index.php?users=$1 [L]
```